# Aggregate only that rows for which probability condition is satisfied

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a procedure that gets a sql query in string. Example:

```
SELECT SUM(Refuse) FROM FOOD_DES WHERE Refuse > 1
```

but I need sum only that rows for which condition is satisfied.
Condition looks like:

```
CONVERT(INT,RAND() * 100 ) <= @probability
```

but this doesnt work (it sums all elements):

```
SELECT SUM(Refuse) FROM FOOD_DES WHERE Refuse > 1 AND
CONVERT(INT,RAND() * 100 ) <= @probability
```

So tried next:

```
SELECT SUM(Refuse) FROM FOOD_DES  AS T CROSS APPLY fn_probability() AS F

CREATE FUNCTION fn_probability ( )
RETURNS @probabilityInfo TABLE ( Result INT )
AS 
    BEGIN 
        DECLARE @rand INT
        SET @rand = ( SELECT TOP 1
                                RandValue
                      FROM      RandView
                    )
        IF @rand <= 80 
            INSERT  INTO @probabilityInfo
                    ( Result )
            VALUES  ( 1 )
        RETURN  
    END
```

> ```
> CREATE VIEW RandView
> AS 
> SELECT CONVERT(INT, RAND() * 100) AS RandValue
> ```

But it doesnt work neither.
Any idea?:)

Comment: +1 for stating what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about like this:

```
WITH data(Refuse, RandomNumber) AS
(
    SELECT 
        Refuse
        ,CONVERT(INT, RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 100) 
    FROM 
        FOOD_DES
    WHERE 
        Refuse > 1
)
SELECT
    SUM(Refuse) 
FROM
    data
WHERE
    RandomNumber <= @probability
```

Comment: It returns the same RandomNumber for each row in data :(

Comment: That's because RAND() does that. [According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177610.aspx): "Repetitive calls of RAND() with the same seed value return the same results." You need to randomize the seed passed into the RAND() function, something like: `RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))`. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

`rand()` itself does not work because it is only executed once during the statement.

When I need a random set of rows, I usually settle for a pseudo random number:

```
select sum(refuse)
from 
(
   SELECT Refuse,
      row_number()  over (partition by null order by (select '')) as rownum
   FROM FOOD_DES
   WHERE Refuse > 1
) t
where mod(rownum*101-67, 100) < @probability
```